# How to Bind data from treeview node to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, treeview

Currently I'm trying to display list of emails on my webpage and I am using Treeview to display email folders and GridView to display contents in the email folders and there is pagination on gridview which should allow to go through list of emails with in respective email folder.

However, On page initial load I'm unable to select page index to getting NullReferenceException. I'm using TV_EmaiBox to retrieve selected node and pass folder value into GetListEmailList method to retrieve emails.

```
protected void GV_EmailList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        GV_EmailList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        string checkFolder = TV_EmaiBox.SelectedNode.Value.ToString();
        this.GetListEmailList(checkFolder);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LB_ActionError.Text = ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        }
    }
```

My GridView code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_EmailList" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
                                        CellPadding="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" BorderStyle="Solid" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GV_EmailList_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GV_EmailList_SelectedIndexChanged" PageSize="5" Width="100%">
                                        <RowStyle BackColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
```

My TreeView Code

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TV_EmaiBox" runat="server" NodeWrap="True" ShowLines="True" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" 
                            ExpandDepth="1" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TV_EmaiBox_SelectedNodeChanged">
                            <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <LeafNodeStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Blue" />
                        </asp:TreeView>
```

I just want to know how can i pass TreeNode value in my GridView Page Index change. Let's say my TreeNode current value is Inbox so OnPageIndexChanging it should display list of emails from that folder.

GetListEmailList Method

```
private void GetListEmailList(string folderName)
    {
        try
        {
            LB_ActionError.Text = string.Empty;
            PH_MsgDetail.Visible = true;

            var emails = EmailMsg.GetEmailListInFolder(folderName);
            LB_CurBox.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} ({1})", folderName, emails.Count);

            int intTotal = emails.Count;
            if (intTotal == 0)
            {
                LB_ActionStatus.Text = Utility.SetActStatus(true, "There is no email message found in this folder.");
                GV_EmailList.DataSource = new ArrayList();
                GV_EmailList.DataBind();
                GV_EmailList.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                LB_ActionStatus.Text = Utility.SetActStatus(true, string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "There are {0} email message(s) found in this folder.", intTotal));
                GV_EmailList.DataSource = emails;
                GV_EmailList.DataBind();
                GV_EmailList.Visible = true;

                GV_EmailList.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LB_ActionStatus.Text = Utility.SetActStatus(false, ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        LB_AdminEmailBox.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Entity.GetSetting("MailBoxAddress"), folderName);
    }
}
```

My Page Load Method

```
 B_EmailMsgDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:if(!doDeleteEmailMsg()) return false;");
        IB_EmailMover.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:if(!doMoveEmailMsg()) return false;");

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TreeNode rootTreeNode = new TreeNode();
            rootTreeNode.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "&nbsp;{0}", this.curEmailBox);
            rootTreeNode.Value = this.EmailFolderList[0];
            rootTreeNode.ImageUrl = "../../Images/emailbox.gif";

            for (int i = 0; i < this.EmailFolderList.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
                    treeNode.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "&nbsp;{0}", this.EmailFolderList[i]);
                    treeNode.Value = this.EmailFolderList[i];
                    treeNode.ImageUrl = "../../Images/folder.gif";
                    rootTreeNode.ChildNodes.Add(treeNode);
                }

                DL_MoveTo.Items.Add(this.EmailFolderList[i]);
            }

            TV_EmaiBox.Nodes.Add(rootTreeNode);
            this.GetListEmailList(rootTreeNode.Value);
        }
```

TresView SelectedNodeChange Method

```
protected void TV_EmaiBox_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string checkFolder = TV_EmaiBox.SelectedNode.Value.ToString();
        this.GetListEmailList(checkFolder);
    }
```

Comment: You need to debug the code and see which variable is null

Comment: When I debug my code error is coming from this line string checkFolder = TV_EmaiBox.SelectedNode.Value.ToString();

Comment: What is null ? SelectedNode or Value? Are you loading data to TreeView in Page_Load?

Comment: Value is null and yes I'm loading TreeView in my Page_Load Method. Let me edit and add my page load method in my question.

Comment: @C0deSlayer I haven't used razor pages before, but I am sure that the model binding is not done correctly. From where should the value be passed to "TV_EmaiBox.SelectedNode.Value"?